# Debugging "Delegate 'sendorpostcallback' does not take 0 arguments"?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Can anyone point to me why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? The part that highlights with the error is after the parenthesis on OP.Post in the lambda expression.

```
    private AsyncOperation OP;
    public event ExceptionThrownEventHandler ExceptionThrown;
    public delegate void ExceptionThrownEventHandler(UClient sender, Exception ex);

    private void OnExceptionThrown(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ExceptionThrown != null)
        {
            ExceptionThrown(this, ex);
        }
    }

    OP.Post(() => OnExceptionThrown(new Exception("Exception description here.")), null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OP.Post()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.post(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a delegate of type [SendOrPostCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback(v=vs.110).aspx), which should have 1 parameter: `object state` (if you look at the documentation).

So, just add the parameter to respect the expected method signature, even if you don't actually use it:

```
OP.Post(state => OnExceptionThrown(new Exception("Exception description here.")), null);
```